# Convolve does not get the correct answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, convolution

```
Convolve[Sinc[x], Exp[-x^2], x, X]
(* E^-X^2 π *)
```

is obviously false, but why?
Any suggestions ?

Comment: My *Mathematica* returns this unevaluated. 10.0.2 on OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Mine too (10.0.2.0 on Win 8.1 x64).

Comment: Consider using different variable names as this brings confusion. `Convolve[Sinc[v], Exp[-w^2], v, w]` evaluates to `E^-w^2 [Pi]` @ Mathematica 9.0.0.1 and Mathematica 10 quits the kernel

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: All of Mathematica 8.0.4, 9.0.1 and 10.0.2 return it unevaluated after a lengthy computation on my computer (OS X 10.10.2).

Comment: @Sektor Are you sure`Convolve[Sinc[v], Exp[-w^2], v, w]` and `Convolve[Sinc[v], Exp[-v^2], v, w]` are the same thing?

Comment: @FelixZhao Good catch.  I copied Sektor's input verbatim without noticing this error.  It returns unevaluated regardless of what variable names I use.

Comment: @FelixZhao Who said they are the same thing ? I tried to reproduce OP's results using the original input (the latter in your comment) and it failed. Then I assumed he meant to use different variables (the former in your comment) and that did the trick. But, no, they are not the same thing :D

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I don't think he's demeaning anyone.  Rather he's identified that the OP got that result from a computation containing a typo... a typo which was not repeated when asking the question.  Looking at related expressions which might explain the observed output is useful, and evidently he got the idea to do so from Wolfram support.

Comment: If you think I am being offensive, I apologize and deleted my post. I do not have any intention to demean anyone, since you may easily find out my identities. I just found things and people here are more helpful than the technical support, as least for me, that's what I meant.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau We just noticed that this really is a bug in `Convolve`. My answer below evaluates to the wrong result in versions 8 and 10.9.5

Comment: @Felix My question/comment is now deleted as well.

Comment: @Jens I'll have a look once I take a moment to stop breaking things this afternoon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$Version

(*
"8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
*)
```

Direct attack fails:

```
Timing[Convolve[Sinc[x], Exp[-x^2], x, y]]

(*
Out[218]= {59.296, Convolve[Sinc[x], E^-x^2, x, y]}
*)
```

or, equivalently,

```
Timing[Integrate[Sinc[x] Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}] ]
```

$\left\{49.92,\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-(x-y)^2} \text{Sinc}[x] \, dx\right\}$

Let us now solve the problem, using Fourier transform.

We have

```
FourierTransform[Sinc[x], x, t]

(*
Out[206]= 1/2 Sqrt[π/2] (Sign[1 - t] + Sign[1 + t])
*)
```

Therefore we can write

```
InverseFourierTransform[1/2 Sqrt[π/2] (Sign[1 - t] + Sign[1 + t]), t, x]

(*
Out[207]= Sin[x]/x
*)
```

or, explicitly

```
Integrate[Exp[-I t x] (1/
    4 (Sign[1 - t] + Sign[1 + t])), {t, -∞, ∞}]

(*
Out[211]= Sin[x]/x
*)
```

Therefore doing the x integration first we have

```
Integrate[Exp[-I t x] (1/
    4 (Sign[1 - t] + Sign[1 + t])) Exp[-(x - 
      y)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(*
Out[212]= 1/4 E^(-(1/4) t (t + 4 I y)) Sqrt[π] (Sign[1 - t] + Sign[1 + t])
*)
```

and the t integration finalizes the calculation giving for the convolution the following result:

```
Integrate[1/4 E^(-(1/4) t (t + 4 I y))
   Sqrt[π] (Sign[1 - t] + Sign[1 + t]), {t, -∞, ∞}]

(*
Out[215]= 1/2 E^-y^2 π (Erf[1/2 - I y] + Erf[1/2 + I y])
*)
```

**EDIT #1**

17.03.15 Comparision and analysis

Let us first compare the answers of Wolfgang and Jens

```
fWolfgang[y_] := 1/2 E^-y^2 π (Erf[1/2 - I y] + Erf[1/2 + I y])

fJens[X_] := -(1/2) E^-X^2 Pi Erfc[1/2 - I X] - 1/2 E^-X^2 Pi Erfc[1/2 + I X]
```

Because $erfc(z) = 1 - erf(z)$ this can be written

```
f1Jens[y_] := -(1/2) E^-y^2 π (1 - Erf[1/2 - I y] + 1 - Erf[1/2 + I y])
```

The difference is just

```
fWolfgang[x] - f1Jens[x] // Simplify

(*
Out[9]= E^-x^2 π
*)
```

Now, in order to see the "true" result, let's define the numeric integral

```
fNum[y_] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[x]/x Exp[-(y - x)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

Comparing the results graphically (ignoring the error messages of the integration) gives

```
Plot[{fWolfgang[y] + 0.1, fNum[y]}, {y, -6, 6}]
(* 150317_Plot _fW _fN *)
```

[image]

"proves" that fWolfgang is correct.

Do you want still another incorrect result from correct input? Here we go:

Writing `Sin[x] = 1/(2 I) (Exp[I x] - Exp[-I x])` our integral becomes

```
fSplit[y_] = 
 Integrate[(Exp[I x] - Exp[-I x])/(2 I x)
    Exp[-(y - x)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(*
Out[16]= 1/2 I E^-y^2 (Log[-I - 2 y] - Log[I - 2 y] + Log[-I + 2 y] - Log[I + 2 y])
*)
```

Here there even is no error function. And the result is obviously wrong:

```
fSplit[0.]

(*
Out[19]= 3.14159 + 0. I
*)

fWolfgang[0.]

(*
Out[20]= 1.6352 + 0. I
*)
```

The same (wrong) result is obtained usind the option `PrincipalValue->True` in order to tell Mathematica how to deal with the false pole at `x = 0`.

But let's look at the ostensible pole in more detail.
This integral is obviously divergent at `x = 0`:

```
Integrate[Exp[I x]/(2 I x) Exp[-(y - x)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

> During evaluation of In[21]:= Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(I
>   x-(-x+y)^2)/x does not converge on {-∞,∞}. >>

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } -\frac{i e^{i x-(-x+y)^2}}{2 x} \, dx$

But taking the pricipal value the result is finite

```
Integrate[Exp[I x]/(2 I x) Exp[-(y - x)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]

(*
Out[22]= 1/2 I E^-y^2 (Log[-I - 2 y] - Log[I + 2 y])
*)
```

and it is part of the wrong result `fSplit[]` above.

The integral can also be written as a fourier transform

```
Sqrt[2 π] FourierTransform[1/(2 I x) Exp[-(y - x)^2], x, t] /. t -> 1

(*
Out[27]= -(1/2) I E^-y^2 (-Log[-I - 2 y] + Log[I + 2 y])
*)
```

But it still leads to the same wrong result.

Summarizing we find that splitting the `Sin[]` into a sum of complex exponentials the resulting integral leads rather consistently to a wrong result.

Concluding

(i) it is not only Convolve which produces wrong results but also related integrals do.

(ii) I realize that I was just lucky having found the correct result by attacking the problem using Fourier transformation.

**EDIT #2**

In order to mitigate the pessimistic outlook here's a positive message:

We can replace the lengthy Fouriertransform approach by this one.

A pole 1/x can be produced by an auxiliary integration.

Indeed, we can write

```
Integrate[Cos[t x], {t, 0, 1}]

(* Out[45]= Sin[x]/x *)
```

Changing the order of integration, doing the x-integral first, we get

```
Integrate[Cos[t x] Exp[-(x - y)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* 
Out[46]= 1/2 E^(-(1/4) t (t + 4 I y)) (1 + E^(2 I t y)) Sqrt[π] 
*)
```

and doing the t-integral subsequently we have

```
Integrate[%, {t, 0, 1}]

(*
Out[47]= 1/2 E^-y^2 π (Erf[1/2 - I y] + Erf[1/2 + I y])
*)
```

which is the correct result.

Check:

% /. y -> 1.

(*
Out[44]= 1.39248 + 0. I
*)

We can also "save" convole.

We have to consider (before the t-integration)

```
Convolve[Cos[t x], Exp[-x^2], x, y]

(*
Out[57]= 1/2 E^(-(1/4) t (t + 4 I y)) (1 + E^(2 I t y)) Sqrt[π]
*)
```

and the t-integral

```
Integrate[%, {t, 0, 1}]

(*
Out[55]= 1/2 E^-y^2 π (Erf[1/2 - I y] + Erf[1/2 + I y])
*)

% /. y -> 1.

(*
Out[56]= 1.39248 + 0. I
*)
```

gives the correct result.

**EDIT #3**

I have found a transparent way to generate the result of Jens.
This show where the problem lies.

Let us again consider the integral

```
h = 1/(2 I )
   Integrate[Exp[I x]/x Exp[(x - y)^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

and let us shift the integration variable thus

```
Exp[I x]/x Exp[-(x - y)^2] /. x -> u + y

(*
Out[66]= E^(-u^2 + I (u + y))/(u + y)
*)
```

completing the square

```
Expand[-(u - I/2)^2]

(*
Out[67]= 1/4 + I u - u^2
*)
```

we can write

$\text{Exp}[i y-1/4]\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-(u-i/2)^2}}{y+u} \, du$

Now shifting again, this time into the complex plane

```
E^-(u - I/2)^2/(y + u) /. u -> v + I/2

(*
Out[68]= E^-v^2/(I/2 + v + y)
*)
```

giving

$\text{Exp}[i y-1/4]\int_{-\infty -i/2}^{\infty -i/2} \frac{e^{-v^2}}{y+v+i/2} \, dv$

Now the trick from the good old university days when calculating the Fourier transform of Exp[-x^2]: 
we shift the integration path in the u-plane which lies 1/2 unitites below the real axis and paralell to it, to the real axis.
This gives

$\frac{1}{2i}\text{Exp}[i y-1/4]\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-w^2}}{y+w+i/2} \, dw$

```
(*
Out[69]= ConditionalExpression[-(1/2) I E^(-(1/4) + I y - 
   1/4 (I + 2 y)^2) (I π Erf[1/2 - I y] + Log[-I - 2 y] - Log[I + 2 y]), 
 Im[y] != -(1/2)]
*)
```

Taking the input format we can add the condition that y>0 (for ins

```
(1/(2*I))*Exp[I*y - 1/4]*
  Integrate[1/(E^w^2*(y + w + I/2)), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> y ∈ Reals] // Simplify

(*
Out[71]= -(1/2) E^-y^2 π Erfc[1/2 - I y]
*)
```

For the complete (sinc) integral we need to add the complex conjugate h* of it, giving

```
fShift[y_] = -(1/2) E^-y^2 π Erfc[1/2 - I y] + -(1/2) E^-y^2 π Erfc[
    1/2 + I y]

(*
Out[72]= -(1/2) E^-y^2 π Erfc[1/2 - I y] - 1/2 E^-y^2 π Erfc[1/2 + I y]
*)
fShift[1.]

(* 
Out[73]= 0.236748 + 0. I 
*)
```

We can easily verify that this function is exactly the result fJens[] of Jens.

This means, however, that the clue lies in the shifting of the integration path. This shifting blurres the required exact treatment of the pole.

**EDIT #4: Miscellaneous results**

1) *Proof by series expansion*

Just to fill a small gap: in the "proof" of correctness of fWolfgang we resorted to numerical integration.

Now we shall do it by expansion into power series

```
fWolfgang[y]

(*
Out[142]= 1/2 E^-y^2 π (Erf[1/2 - I y] + Erf[1/2 + I y])
*)

Series[fWolfgang[y], {y, 0, 6}] // Normal

(*
Out[154]= π Erf[1/2] + y^2 (Sqrt[π]/E^(1/4) - π Erf[1/2]) + 
 y^6 ((71 Sqrt[π])/(360 E^(1/4)) - 1/6 π Erf[1/2]) + 
 y^4 (-((7 Sqrt[π])/(12 E^(1/4))) + 1/2 π Erf[1/2])
*)
```

Expanding the expression `Exp[-(x-y)^2]` in the integrand with respect to `y`, and integrating term by term gives up to the order `y^6`:

```
Collect[Integrate[
   Sin[x]/x Series[Exp[-(x - y)^2], {y, 0, 6}] // 
    Normal, {x, -∞, ∞}] // Expand, y]

(*
Out[163]= π Erf[1/2] + y^2 (Sqrt[π]/E^(1/4) - π Erf[1/2]) + 
 y^6 ((71 Sqrt[π])/(360 E^(1/4)) - 1/6 π Erf[1/2]) + 
 y^4 (-((7 Sqrt[π])/(12 E^(1/4))) + 1/2 π Erf[1/2])
*)
```

which agrees with the expansion of fWolfgang.

This is not a strict proof, of course, as we have considered only a finite number of terms.
But I promise to the first one who finds a term which does not agree a bottle of fine German beer.

2) *The innocent "pole"*

The "pole" at x = 0 alone is not the cause of trouble.

Look at this example where I have replaced the Gaussian by a Cauchy weight

```
Convolve[(Sin[x]/x), 1/(1 + x^2), x, y, Assumptions -> y > 0]

(*
Out[197]= (π (E - Cos[y] + y Sin[y]))/(E (1 + y^2))
*)
```

or, in explicit form,

```
Integrate[(Sin[x]/x) 1/(1 + (x - y)^2), {x, -∞, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> y > 0]

(*
Out[200]= (π (E - Cos[y] + y Sin[y]))/(E (1 + y^2))
*)
```

Both operations are performed by Mathematica without problems.

I conclude that it is the combination of the "pole" and the esssential singularity of Exp[-x^2] at infinity which gives rise to the observed difficulties.

Comment: You are right , another answer could be :

In[84]:=
InverseFourierTransform[ Sqrt[Pi/2] UnitBox[t/2], t, x]

Out[84]=
Sinc[x]

In[85]:=
InverseFourierTransform[ 1/Sqrt[2] Exp[-(t/2)^2], t, x]

Out[85]= E^-x^2

In[86]:=
FourierTransform[UnitBox[t/2] Sqrt[Pi/2] 1/Sqrt[2] Exp[-(t/2)^2], t, x]

Out[86]= 1/2 E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (Erf[1/2-I x]+Erf[1/2+I x])

 But, is there an option in Convolve to get the right answer directly ?

Comment: I always enjoy your detailed analyses and answers. +1

Comment: Your answer is probably the only one that works because `Convolve` in my answer is buggy. In that case, I think the question is actually a duplicate of [Convolving/integrating problems](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25970/245).

Comment: @rasher: thank you very much for your kind remark which made my day :-) As a reward I have taken the liberty to continue the analysis a bit (see my EDIT #1)

Comment: I like that change-of-order (edit#2). Cannot give a second upvote though.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis in  edit #3. I already upvoted you before giving my own answer... couldn't believe that I actually stumbled on a bug there.

Comment: @Dr Hintze : Thank you for your analysis and to show the bad treatment of the pole in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way that allows you to directly use `Convolve`:

```
Convolve[TrigToExp@FunctionExpand[Sinc[x]], Exp[-x^2], x, X]

(*
==> -(1/2) E^-X^2 Pi Erfc[1/2 - I X] - 
 1/2 E^-X^2 Pi Erfc[1/2 + I X]
*)
```

In order to get a successful evaluation, I just had to break up the `Sinc` function into its complex exponential terms.

Comment: Nice answer ! Thank you.

Comment: Well. Humm I am sorry for my enthusiast answer yesterday, but Convolve doesnt work again. If i plot the answer (Jens) and the answer (Dr Hintze),Jens result is wrong. Convolve is the problem, because TrigToExp@FunctionExpand[Sinc[x]] works.

Comment: Right, this seems to be a huge bug in `Convolve`.

Comment: I did some testing and sent along in house what I found. Agreed, it's a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for taking a look. It's sneaky because the `c` in `Erfc` is easy to overlook, and with `Erf` it would almost be right (up to a sign).